# Real time updating of an indicator without polling

Tags: php, reactjs, real-time

I have overtaken a project that uses core php and react as frontend,

In the page, it has a team indicator, basically ***enrolled team / max team***,

Now, I wanted the team indicator to be realtime, but would like to avoid polling as it will exhaust the server.

One thing I can think of is websocket, but I have read that it's going to be obsolete, and would like to know a long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) will probably fit your exact use case, since you don't need to send anything to the server, but just receive data.

On the other hand, polling might still be a viable solution, as long as you're smart about it. Have a caching layer that stores the current indicator status (could be in memory, or in a file, Redis, Memcache, anything really) do PHP doesn't need to recalculate the status on every request. This way, your chances of 'exhausting' the server will be basically zero. Also, polling once a second, or once every few seconds, is usually fast enough. Do you really need *actual* real-time feedback?